# When should we have elections?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

I've been using other SE sites for quite a long time when I discovered Islam SE, completely to my surprise it has been running for a long time and still Beta! I have objections to many policies around here most of them already discussed on meta!!

for example irresponsible deletions just to enforce what they think is right without caring to involve the community "*It was not good, Deleted, Period!*".
I want a community where a mod would comment on a high up-voted answer to show he respects the votes and the efforts of the responder.

I do respect the mods here, and I find them great Muslims! But I think **they've become really far from the community** and are acting on their own more than acting by the will of community and for the good of community!!

- I don't want to discuss what is wrong and what is right in their actions, I just find that we need new people who are from the community.
- I think mods exist to enforce community policies not their own policies.
- Mods need to be trusted by the majority or it will disappoint many from bringing up their issues and hoping it will be attended fairly

I'm very new here, right! But I want this place to grow up. **Please don't consider this personal or any sect war**! I'm just thinking about making this place get better and let more people to know the true Islam. So I recommend elections for new mods, do you agree?

Comment: Only graduated sites elect their moderators.  For beta sites, they're appointed directly by the Stack Exchange team.

Comment: I know that, but if it's like this I think the community will never graduate or it will take so long .

Comment: When will the community get out of beta?

Comment: @Mhmd http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Comment: @BleedingFingers thanks, I think we should work harder to get out of beta.

Comment: @Mhmd [Long way to go](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1013/3487).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** It is kind of unfair that I posted this as an answer to one old meta post rather than as stand alone post. I might eventually make a separate post out of this, but I'd like to at least note that *the following is in regard to a general problem, not just the user that opened this meta question*. In fact the user that originally posted this has since [posted a follow up with a completely different tune](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1304/75). That should reflect on them personally more than my comments below.

At the same time this *does still apply to this site and many of its users. I stand behind what I have said*.

---

I understand you want your site to graduate and you are frustrated that is not happening faster. Discussing the reasons for that and orchestrating change to make that dream a reality is the right thing to do. That being said please allow me to make an observation as someone not directly involved in this site but who has quite a bit of experience with SE sites in general including helping to pilot one of the religion sites through successful graduation. I've been reading through a number of recent meta discussions and see a trend. And it's not a good one.

For the sake of making sure the point is made I am going to say this bluntly, but please believe me when I say my motivation for this is not to rag on you or run your site down. I'm suggesting something from experience that I think will help you. You can choose to read this as offensive or choose to read it as an attempt to suggest a constructive way forward. While not a Muslim myself I do live in the Middle East and am well versed in the issues faced by religious study and dialogue in real life as well as the specific issues that Stack Exchange sites face.

All that being said here is my observation. The attitude I see exhibited in this post is part of the problem, not part of the solution. It's not just this post either, I see all over your meta right now.

Seriously when it comes to the issue of whether a community like this one is healthy (and ready to graduate) you have the problem and the solution mixed up--your talking about the problem as if it was a solution and the solution as if it was a problem. Your moderators aren't perfect, but they have been chosen by the SE specifically because they have demonstrated some understanding of the principals that SE sites work on. In fact I think you have a pretty good selection of *pro tempore* mods. The problem is you aren't listening to them. The problem is not that the "mods are far from the community" the problem seems to be that a large portion of the current community has wandered far from the basics of what makes SE sites work and a lot of you are all blatantly ignoring perfectly good advice from your mods.

I know some of what they have to say is counter intuitive and different from what most internet venues do, but those very things you are actively rejecting are what make most successful SE sites so good. Ignoring and even working against your mods is no way to work toward graduation. On the contrary its a fast track to failure and getting shut down. Is that what you want?

If you want to graduate you are going to need to stop trying to make this like every other internet forum and stop trying to be all things to all people. Instead you need to step back and make the effort to learn what makes SE sites unique, figure out how to apply those things to your subject matter and focus on just those things. Among other things this will mean all of you pitching in to promote a broader understanding that not all questions are automatically good for this site. You need to do less objecting to everything your mods do and start getting behind them as they try to pilot your site towards graduation. They won't always be right but discuss it with them and try to understand the things they explain rather than just fighting them on every point.

Stop being part of the problem and start helping with the solutions. Support your mods! Show some appreciation for their efforts even when you disagree. Listen and learn from them what you can.

The same goes for the high rep users that are doing things like voting to close. You can disagree with them sometimes but respect the fact that they are volunteering their time to improve the site and even when you disagree work with them to try to work out what is best for the long term needs of the site rather than trying to insist all questions are to be blanketly approved even when they have aspects that work against what this site set out to be.

Comment: I have been on this site right from the start. From my experience, moderation here is big problem indeed. Many things are taken personnel, bullying, disrespectful language is used in the chat. One mode demands *respect* when talking to him. No mod I believe have tried to promote the site or welcome new users. In fact new post (and old ones) are deleted blantendly. One or two post of mine were deleted as well, I was told by mo, ask them again as he won't undelete it. There is a big ego problem here.

Comment: The big issue here is of sectarianism. What I have seen (and I could be wrong) that shia users life have been made miserable here. They have no choice but to quite after repeatedly asking question on meta with no help. It is more of *personnel war*. I believe mods needs to be totally unbiased, accommodative and polite, which has not been the case here, esp with one or two.

Comment: @muslim1 I'm not saying sectarianism is not as issue for you guys, but that's been tackled elsewhere and the main problem I saw browsing your meta was this issue. Your experience with chat moderation doesn't make much sense as an objection to my post here. If anything it proves my point. If you think a mod is being disrespectful, then post about it here and we'll straighten it out. The meta posts I do see suggest just the opposite: users being disrespectful and mods just doing their job. If anything they aren't being strict enough and the users are making it hard on them by being recalcitrant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even after so long, Actually the matter goes to an era where I experienced a dictatorship like sectarianism where, I felt like I was unable to communicate with others, and it was all because I was in another sect than the mod. I felt like the mod was misusing the power to advertise his own sect rather than help the community. But it was resolved later and I learned to cope with the problem. This post as I read it again now seems very naive to me. I'm sorry for not being constructive

Comment: @Bludream Thanks for replying. I'm sorry if this came off harsh on you. It was really more about the whole current scene on meta and I probably should have posted a new meta post instead of pick on this one. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Bludream your assumption that mods here are more like `dictators` is absolutely correct. A mod does not take *any critique* at all, esp one mod. Also the problem here is overwhelming sectarian. I have said before, if you put Sunni post under the same standards you put shia post, I am sure a huge number should be deleted but they are not because all mods are of Sunni sect. That's just my opinion.

Comment: I just noticed that this post of mine on meta was deleted, not sure why. http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1164/279 . Anything slightly against moderators is not tolerated, that is dictatorship.

Comment: @muslim1, http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1304/4710

Comment: @Caleb, I appreciate adding the `Edit`

Comment: @Bludream And I appreciate your willingness to actually examine the issue and speak up about the things you've learned here. I hope that will set a good example for others to do the same.