# Why was my answer about "this site is in trouble" post deleted on meta?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answer, deletion

My answer to this [Take pride in your community, and work to build a site you can be proud of](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of/1164#1164) was deleted. It is a very important concern brought by one of the SE moderator. **I voiced my concern and opinion as well but it got deleted.**

I guess I am concerned about this site like anybody else. I raised it in my answer but I guess a mod does not like it and delete it.

Notice the answer by @Mhmd which *does not* touch the original post but it stays. There really is one of the major problem here on SE, moderation is totally opinion based here and grossly biased.

**Please clarify, If I am not allowed to raise my concern in this SE moderator post, where am I am suppose to raise it? Thx**

My deleted post is below since most users won't be able to see it. It is only partially view.[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the original reason for deletion (I suspect there were comments involved that you are not showing us), but here are some reasons I think it should stay deleted:

1. It is not an answer to the question you posted it under. It does not build on the idea that was being presented there. It's relevant only in that it is *your personal opinion* about the state of the site.
2. Most of the things you say in that post you have said elsewhere on meta. You have both answers and dedicated questions already that cover much of the same content, sometimes word for word. Not every meta post about the state of the site is an appropriate venue for you to get on your soap-box all over again.
3. It has too many unrelated points for constructive feedback as an answer. Each of those would be better dealt with on meta as separate meta posts where the community can reply to and discuss the specific issue. This goes back to #1, but changing the topic in an answer means people are limited to comments to reply rather than being able to post full answers.
4. Your argument that another unrelated answer was allowed to stand therefore yours should to in completely invalid seeing as how the other unrelated answer was also asked to repost as a separate meta post. Just because somebody else made a similar mistake and it hasn't been resolved yet does not give you an excuse to make the same 'mistake' on purpose. That's a childish line of reasoning.

In the mean time **I suggest you carefully read [my recent post about attitudes on meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1298/75)**. That stuff applies to you personally even more than it does to the post I was replying under. You're tone here is not constructive! Stop making this a personality issue and stick to issues of content or specific actions. Saying things like "moderation [...] here [is] grossly biased" does nothing to identify or fix a problem. That just comes across like you are trying to pick a fight. How about A) listening to and trying to understand where other people are coming from when they disagree with you and B) identifying specific content issues and suggesting solutions rather than making ad-hominem attacks on moderators.

Lastly you need to adapt and learn to accept the decisions from the community even when you may still disagree. I see some of your past meta posts have raised specific issues. The answers you have gotten explain in detail why they disagree with you about either the nature of the problem or the solution, and voting clearly indicates community support for those positions. You need to adapt and learn from those incidents rather that keep bringing them up over and over and fighting the same issues.

Comment: His post was directly attacking moderators, that could be a reason too.

Comment: @Mhmd Pass me a tin-foil hat please. Apparently some of you want to blame the moderators for everything, but the evidence I see doesn't stand up. The last part of muslim1's deleted post (which he does not show in it's entirety) does indeed personally attack the moderators. The thing is the exact same attack (almost word for word) is posted as a separate meta post and it was allowed to stand, so obviously that isn't the problem. **Have you considered that that meta post is just the wrong venue for the content he was trying to post?** Seriously, the accusation you are making is unfounded.

Comment: I'm not blaming anyone. I'm saying that his post might be considered as offensive by someone so he flagged it as such.

Comment: @Mhmd Alright I'm sorry if I miss-understood what you meant there. I still don't the likely scenario for deletion has anything to do with it being a moderator that was mentioned, being off-topic for the question is the far more likely (and still valid) scenario.

Comment: I personally think this answer is biased as well *based on my past posts*. My copied answer above hardly contains any thing against moderators which this answer blames me for. Sure I did not show the entire answer because it was longer. It was the mods who choose to remove it not me. Right, point no 4 down the line was against moderations. Point no 5 in the post  was in favor of moderation. Sorry I don't agree with cut and past `word by word`. I raised issues else where specifically about different things. In this answer, I talked about all the issues that plagued the site.

Comment: @Caleb Lastly the comments were not destructive *at all*. In fact they were really really useful and actually advised me I could be wrong! I will be happy to cut and past the entire answer to you if interested. Above all, it was my opinion (and I am no absolute authority). I still believe all these factors are the problem with the site and I voiced it. I did not voice it anywhere else in the same fashion.

Comment: E.g. I tell a moderator he shouldn't delete comments on meta by saying comments are not for discussion, and he should delegate when he is personally involved and he deletes my comment and later says comments are annoying him. Is that what we should expect from a moderator? We should not turn a blind eye to this and similar cases just because they are moderators and they need to sustain their authority to able to act effectively and we have some other problems they are dealing with. They should be clearly told not to misuse moderator powers.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment though I don't think it was FUD. I understand they are working hard but I think they can and should do better. I leave the comment above as an example of an unnecessary deletion.

Comment: @Kaveh It sounds like you may be using the wrong venue at the wrong time too. If you would like to clarify the guidelines on comment deletion or question a specific instance of it, raise a meta post specifically about that. That will allow both mods and the community to give you feedback and if something is amiss has a chance of setting it right. It sounds like the issue was off-topic comments and you leaving more off-topic comments does not help! Cleaning that sort of thing up is exactly what mods are for, that is not a misuse of power (and makes  your point about delegation irrelevant).

Comment: @Caleb A few moderators != community. Never was Meta or Islam SE about community, definitely not from the time I started. It is always about a moderator making a rule and everyone having to follow it.