# Do mods come straight from hell if they are not the way we want them to be?

Tags: discussion

I'm not that active here(very busy, nothing else), but I have been in a phase that I think sharing it may help some others who are feeling like what I felt.

first days when I came here I posted answers which were in the category of plagiarism or had some other problems and some were deleted because a mod didn't like them. The latter reason made me really angry and furious it was like boom "uhh people I'm under oppression and these mods are pure evil" .

#### we need to understand here we are all brothers and in pursue of truth !

I did really felt that time just like how you might be feeling now!! But it doesn't help the way you're dealing with it. By being furious and posting against mods everywhere, this will be like the problem is you. Don't ever think mods are coming from hell if they are not the way you want them to be, instead work in the community and reason with them about the matter, believe me we are mostly thinking like each other just with different backgrounds; we can always easily make other members to understand the matter and help us by posting in meta.

- Please let us all be constructive, fighting here will not help since we are all on the same side.
- I don't say we should defend mods, but we should criticize all their actions in order to gradually develop a perfect community. A fight is not a criticism.
- (some powers given to mods are really absurd) still we need to learn to respect each other and remember we are really brothers.

we might be from different sects and might always want to tell others about it and invite them to it, but do let others do it too and then we can reason about which belief from which sect seems closer to the true Islam. let your beliefs be challenged and try to find reasons for what you believe in by discussing with others, but a fight will never help.

Remember we all believe in la ilaha illa allah (لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله), don't just count someone who might be thinking or believing in another way as going to hell, rather than trying to reason with him.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for or what your message is

Comment: @Muslim I disagree, meta *is* a place for such type of discussion and this post is trying to solve a huge problem we have on this site: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=goldpseudo+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @bludream,very nice...we are all brothers and in pursue of truth!+1

Comment: The problem is moderators sometime overuse their powers and in case of protest they don't care to explain the reason for their actions. This gives the user the impression that the mods can use and overuse their powers with impunity.

Comment: I disagree with infaturated, Mods have explained why they did so and so.  But it is the users who keep bothering them after they received a response from the mods

Comment: I think, mods are doing a good job maintaining a balance. It's hard to monitor due to the nature of questions that tend to raise conflicts. I am not a mod, but I myself find it difficult when I try to answer/comment a question that needs clearly moderation. I pray, may Allah ease us in this process.